# how can I get the ClassType from a Class method?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

How do I return the type of a class in a class method?

In a regular method, I can use `self.ClassType`, but there doesn't seem to be a class method on TObject that achieves this (although I can get the `ClassName`).

```
class function TSomething.MyClass: TClass;
begin
  //what goes here?
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a class method the TClassType is just `Self`

```
class function TSomething.MyClass: TClass;
begin
  result := Self;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just answered this for myself.